# Is there a REST API to access Mesos Replicated Log library?

Tags: mesos

Apache Aurora uses Mesos Replicated Log using JNI library. I suppose there is no REST API support ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is currently no REST API to the Mesos replicated log. There has been talk about building such a thing in the past, but AFAIK nothing has been completed.

Comment: Can you link to the talk?

Comment: I think Neil Conway meant to say, this issue has been *talked/discussed* about in the past but nothing happened.